# Double/compound verbs?

Tags: verbs

In the following phrases, there is something like a "compound verb" (I really don't know what you call them.)

ものすごい速さで飛び立ちました

私の持ってきたかけらと

What difference would it make if instead of 飛び立ちました we just say 飛びました？ Or 持った？ Is it for emphasis only? Or it sounds more natural this way?

Lastly, is there a correct name to identify these kinds of "double verbs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without context

> ものすごい速さで飛びました

might mean "**flew** with incredible speed" rather than "**jumped up** with incredible speed". The 立ち part makes it clear that some standing up is involved. As a non-native I don't know if this is a valid alternative.

As for the second sentence, 持ってくる = "bring", 持っていく = "take away", but 持つ is simply "to have/own". So in this case I think the くる is essential.

Compund verb is 複合動詞. I think the second example isn't really a compund verb though. It's just two verbs joined with て形.

You can find a list of compound verbs and meanings [here](http://vvlexicon.ninjal.ac.jp/db/).

Comment: Apologies for the bad translation of 飛び立つ (see @chocolate's) answer. I think the rest is okay so I won't delete.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the other answer, 飛び立つ is a compound verb (複合動詞), since the 飛び is in the continuative form (連用形).

飛ぶ is just "fly/jump", while 飛び立つ is "fly away" or "take off". I think the 立つ adds the meaning of "to leave", rather than "to stand". (I don't know if the 立つ has anything to do with [発]{た}つ, though.)

I think the くる(来る) in 持ってくる is a subsidiary verb (補助動詞), since it's attached to a te-form verb. Other examples of て形 + 補助動詞: 見ていく、見てみる、見ておく、見てくれる、見てもらう、見てあげる...

持ってくる consists of 持つ "to have/carry" + 来る "to come (here/this way)", so it means "bring here".

Answer (score 0):

飛び立つ is one single word, with its own entry in the dictionary:
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/54920/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%B3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A4/
Even though etymologically it is made up of 2 different verbs, grammatically it is just one word.

飛び立つ means to "to fly and go away".
飛ぶ means just "to fly".
So the meaning is slightly different.

Comment: http://www.kanjifumi.jp/keyword/fu/